# How can I change the text on the tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins

Is there some Firefox plugin that I can use to change the text on the tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[TabRenamizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2987)** does exactly what you want:

- Random rename tabs: change the titles of your tabs to random ones with a simple click. Nobody will suspect what pages are you reading...
- Select a new title for a tab, writing it or replacing a substring of the original title into another text.
- URL and domain automatic rename: rename all tabs with a certain URL or domain with the title you want, automatically.
- Bookmark integration: give the pages the same title you have in your bookmarks.

[image]

Comment: There is something entierly distrubing with your example. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) and expand the `<head>` tag, find `<title>` and edit that.

I just tested on this site, and it works...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Definitely a very creative solution to it! I like it!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted it done automatically, you could change the `<title>` as Will says, but using a Greasemonkey script.